# PowerShell 5.1 Not working,not allowing to Run any Script/Cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am getting a weird error while opening PS, either CLI or ISE. In ISE I am not able to run any script or any cmdlet, it shows some script is running and both **RUN buttons are greyed out** and the only option active is **STOP** and nothing is happening, if we stop it. It allows typing,  but does not allow running the cmdlet.

I am attaching the screen shot for reference, I also verified that no script file is there in the profile which is getting executed.

Note- PS was working perfectly till last week, all of a sudden this started. I am using Windows 10 with PS 5.1
[image: ISE Screen]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Launch a [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) or Powershell [ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell_ise) session from cmd with `-NoProfile` switch. Is the problem still present?

Comment: No luck,still same error

Comment: Did you get the Windows 10 2004 update in the meantime? If so, the ExecutionPolicy has been reverted to Restricted.. Start PowerShell as administrator and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` (or `ByPass`)

Comment: You can also do this in the registry:

(All users) Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell`. Create a string (REG_SZ) entry called `ExecutionPolicy` and set its value to `Unrestricted`.
For the current user only, do this in key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell`